# How can I grab the rows from a specific table using an XPATH expression - mine seems to grab all the rows in the document

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have read in a file and created a tree using

```
my_tree = html.fromstring(html_string)
```

Then I separated all of the tables

```
tables = my_tree.xpath('//table')
```

Now I have been playing with the tables I am trying to develop an approach to find the closest match in the document to a model table.  I was listing all of the attributes I could consider and thought about trying to find a way to implement consideration of the number of rows in each table to compare to the number of rows in my test table.

So I did

```
table_lens = [len(table.xpath('//tr')) for table in tables]
```

The interesting thing is that all values in my table_lens list are the same.

I think that the value is the total number of tr in the document (it seems roughly correct)

I expected to have a unique value corresponding to the number of rows in each table.

Now this is interesting because I also 'looked' at the tr elements for two tables by

```
for tr in tables[20].xpath('//tr'):
    tr
```

And a cursory inspection shows that the tr elements dumped each reference the same memory location so I then did

```
tables[20].xpath('//tr') == tables[50].xpath('//tr')
```

and the interpreter returned

```
True
```

So this is fascinating - I thought I would be working with just the rows that belong to a particular table but instead I am getting all of the rows in all of the tables.

On top of all of this I should note that the table[index].text_content() for each table[index] is unique.

To confirm that each table in tables is unique I also did tis

```
>>> tables[20]
<Element table at 0x3260e60>
>>> tables[50]
<Element table at 0x3273570>
>>>
```

Abarnert's comment below suggested the behavior is due to something about the file.  Interesting possibility but after the comment was posted I did a second file and got the same results.  But here is an example htm file

```
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/22252/000119312512253074/d360877ddef14a.htm
```

In this second example there are 33 unique tables and each has 173 tr

Comment: Can you give us a sample input file that demonstrates the behavior you want us to solve for you, instead of making us try to guess what might be the problem?

Comment: @abarnert Thanks I figured the most durable way to provide an example was to post a link to an example.

Comment: OK, I'm an idiot; there's an obvious problem. Let me write an answer.

Comment: You are not the idiot I am the one struggling with this problem I beat my head against the monitor for sometime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath, `//tr` is an absolute path—all tr nodes from the top of the document. `tr` is a relative path—all tr nodes under the current node. It's just like using `/foo` instead of `foo` in a filename.

So, just do this:

```
table_lens = [len(table.xpath('tr')) for table in tables]
```

And you'll get a variety of different numbers from 1 to 14 (or maybe more, I didn't look at the whole list).

Comment: Thats awesome and an important fact to remember lxml is referencing the document with // not the element that is being manipulated